# Utilization of the Multiton pattern

Tags: java, thread-safety, multiton

See [Wikipedia - Multiton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern) for details on the intent.

Here's the class:

```
/**
 * Holds a thread-safe map of unique create-once items.
 * 
 * Contract:
 * 
 * Only one object will be made for each key presented.
 * 
 * Thread safe.
 *
 * @param <K>
 * @param <V>
 */
public class Multiton<K, V> {
  // Map from the key to the futures of the items.
  private final ConcurrentMap<K, Future<V>> multitons = new ConcurrentHashMap<K, Future<V>>();
  // A Prayer is used to construct the Callable that is attached to the FutureTask.
  private final Prayer prayer;

  public Multiton(Creator<K, V> creator) {
    // Create the prayer to the creator.
    this.prayer = new Prayer(creator);
  }

  /**
   * There can be only one.
   * 
   * Use a FutureTask to do the creation to ensure only one construction.
   * 
   * @param key
   * @return
   * @throws InterruptedException
   * @throws ExecutionException 
   */
  public V getInstance(final K key) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    // Already made?
    Future<V> f = multitons.get(key);
    if (f == null) {
      // Plan the future but do not create as yet.
      FutureTask<V> ft = new FutureTask<V>(prayer.pray(key));
      // Store it.
      f = multitons.putIfAbsent(key, ft);
      if (f == null) {
        // It was successfully stored - it is the first (and only)
        f = ft;
        // Make it happen.
        ft.run();
      }
    }
    // Wait for it to finish construction and return the constructed.
    return f.get();
  }

  /**
   * Use a Prayer to pass the key to the Creator.
   *
   * @param <K>
   * @param <V>
   */
  private class Prayer {
    private final Creator<K, V> creator;

    public Prayer(Creator<K, V> creator) {
      this.creator = creator;
    }

    public Callable<V> pray(final K key) {
      return new Callable<V>() {

        @Override
        public V call() throws Exception {
          return creator.create(key);
        }

      };
    }

  }

  /**
   * User provides one of these to do the construction.
   * 
   * @param <K>
   * @param <V> 
   */
  public abstract static class Creator<K, V> {
    // Return a new item under the key.
    abstract V create(K key) throws ExecutionException;

  }

}
```

I use it to ensure I only create one `JAXBContex` for each class:

```
/**
 * Create just one JAXB context for each class.
 */
private static final Multiton<Class, JAXBContext> contexts = new Multiton<Class, JAXBContext>(new Creator<Class, JAXBContext>() {

  @Override
  JAXBContext create(Class key) throws ExecutionException {
    try {
      // Get it out of my Multiton
      return JAXBContext.newInstance(key);
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
      // Pass it back as an Execution Exception.
      throw new ExecutionException("Failed to create JAXB Context for class "+key.getName(), ex);
    }
  }

});

/**
 * Uses a Multiton to create a JAXB context for the object.
 * 
 * @param it - The object to create the context for.
 * @return - the unique JAXB context.
 * @throws InterruptedException - Interrupted.
 * @throws ExecutionException - Something else went wrong (cause is wrapped)
 */
private static JAXBContext createJAXBContext(Object it) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
  return contexts.getInstance(it.getClass());
}
```

### My Questions:

1. Is this a `Multiton` as described by the article? I.e. Will it only ever create just **one** instance of the object?
2. Is it thread-safe?
3. Am I being offensive using a `Prayer` object to request an object from the `Creator`?
4. If the answer to 3 is no - should I make my `create` method of the `Creator` take a `Prayer` as a parameter rather than a `K key` - just for the belly laugh of course?

NB: The idea of using a `FutureTask` came from a nice answer by [assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829571/assylias) on [thread-safe multitons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18149547/823393). All I've really done is make it generic and plumbed in the ability to pass a `Creator`.

Comment: Hmmm, a `Prayer` class with a `prey` method. Now that's not the same thing, is it?

Comment: I'd call it a 'Factory' class.

Comment: @ChrisW - agreed - but that wouldn't be funny any more. :)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg - should we then perhaps `offer` a prayer? :)

Comment: Or we could call the method `pray`.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg - Ah!!! Fixed that - thank you.

Comment: Hmm I thought "multiton" was something that weighted several tons. lol.upvoted.

Comment: @lol.upvote - do I not get a lol.upvote for *gratuitous use of methods of communications with deities in Java*?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon that went without saying :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your use-case and the Wiki description are different. Technically, the Multiton should return the exact same intance for the exact same key, always, but, because your `multitons` Map is not a `static` instance, you can simply create multiple instances of the `Multiton` and each one will generate different instances for the same key.

This is OK in your case, because you create a `private static final` anonymous implementation of the class.... so you handle that problem at a higher level.

I think, otherwise, the algorithm is good.... (i.e. it will work as advertised).

There are two changes I can recommend....

1. Why is the `Creator<K,V>` a `public abstract static` class? This is a broken pattern, and it should simply be an interface `public interface Creator<K,V>`
2. This is complicated, the rest of the answer is about change 2....

I believe you have unnecessary indirection. Your inner class:

> ```
>   private class Prayer {
>     private final Creator<K, V> creator;
>
>     public Prayer(Creator<K, V> creator) {
>       this.creator = creator;
>     }
>
>     public Callable<V> pray(final K key) {
>       return new Callable<V>() {
>
>         @Override
>         public V call() throws Exception {
>           return creator.create(key);
>         }
>
>       };
>     }
>
>   }
> ```

This is overkill.... if you make the Prayer class *Extend* Callable, you win:

```
  private class Prayer implements Callable<V> {
    private final K key;

    public Prayer(K key) {
      this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public V call() throws Exception {
      // creator is accessible as a final field on the Multiton instance.
      return creator.create(key);
    }

  }
```

Then, instead of keeping a final instance to `Prayer` in your main class:

> ```
> private final Prayer prayer;
> ```

you should instead hold the simple Creator:

```
private final Creator<K,V> creator;
```

And, instead of calling `prayer.pray()`, you only need do:

```
FutureTask<V> ft = new FutureTask<V>(new Prayer(key));
```

**Note:** It is much better to request a `new Prayer(...)` than it is to demand one with `prayer.pray()` !!!

---

Hope this all makes sense.... I have reworked your original code as:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

public class Multiton<K, V> {
  // Map from the key to the futures of the items.
  private final ConcurrentMap<K, Future<V>> multitons = new ConcurrentHashMap<K, Future<V>>();
  // A Creator is used to construct the Callable that is attached to the FutureTask.
  private final Creator<K,V> creator;

  public Multiton(Creator<K, V> creator) {
    this.creator = creator;
  }

  /**
   * There can be only one.
   * 
   * Use a FutureTask to do the creation to ensure only one construction.
   * 
   * @param key
   * @return
   * @throws InterruptedException
   * @throws ExecutionException 
   */
  public V getInstance(final K key) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    // Already made?
    Future<V> f = multitons.get(key);
    if (f == null) {
      // Plan the future but do not create as yet.
      FutureTask<V> ft = new FutureTask<V>(new Prayer(key));
      // Store it.
      f = multitons.putIfAbsent(key, ft);
      if (f == null) {
        // It was successfully stored - it is the first (and only)
        f = ft;
        // Make it happen.
        ft.run();
      }
    }
    // Wait for it to finish construction and return the constructed.
    return f.get();
  }

  /**
   * Use a Prayer to pass the key to the Creator.
   *
   * @param <K>
   * @param <V>
   */
  private class Prayer implements Callable<V> {
    private final K key;

    public Prayer(K key) {
      this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public V call() throws Exception {
      return creator.create(key);
    }

  }

  /**
   * User provides one of these to do the construction.
   * 
   * @param <K>
   * @param <V> 
   */
  public interface Creator<K, V> {
    // Return a new item under the key.
    abstract V create(K key) throws ExecutionException;

  }

}
```

Comment: On the `abstract/interface` point - you are absolutely correct. Fixed that now.

Comment: On the `Prayer.pray/Prayer implements Callable` question - I did it this way to minimise the gratuitous construction of objects. My technique will **only** create a `Callable` **once** for each actual construction. Yours may create more than one under a thread storm. I accept that yours is neater and at a trivial cost so I suspect it is better.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon - respectfully, I disagree with your assertion that you were only creating one Callable in a storm... every time you called `pray()` you created a Callable... This is no different.

Comment: Agreed - but `pray` will only be called when the `FutureTask` is **run** so it won't be called if the `putIfAbsent` finds it present. You are creating a new `Prayer` for every `FutureTask`, I create a new `Prayer` for each `Multiton`. My argument is trivial because we create a new `FutureTask` every time anyway so I am not saving anything much and the gain in cleanliness with your solution outweighs that to my mind.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon - hate to labour it... sure, in my version, Prayer **is** a Callable, in yours, it **generates** a callable. We both create a new Callable at the exact same point. In your case, `new FutureTask<V>(prayer.pray(key))`. here `prayer.pray(key)` creates an anonymous Callable instance. In my case, I do `new FutureTask<V>(new Prayer(key))`, which **is** a Callable. It is important you understand your own logic (not because I'm bashing you on this 'just because')... Perhaps join us in [the 2nd monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)?